# When will the value of $X$ and $Y$ be equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

$a$ and $b$ are arrays of Integers.

P and Q are Integers.

> $$X=a[1]\cdot P^1 + a[2] \cdot P^2 + \dots + a[n] \cdot P^n$$
>
> $$Y = b[1] \cdot P^1 + b[2] \cdot P^2 + \dots + b[m]\cdot P^m$$
>
> When will these 2 be equal?

What about these two expressions given below?

$$R=a[1] \cdot P^1 + a[2] \cdot P^2 + \dots + a[n] \cdot P^n$$

$$T = b[1] \cdot Q^1 + b[2] \cdot Q^2 + \dots + b[m] \cdot Q^m$$

Comment: What are $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: What equality do you consider? You mean that they take the same value or that they are the same polynomial?

Comment: Added more detail. Thanks!

Comment: The polynomials $X(t),Y(t)$ satisfy $\,X(P) = Y(P)\iff P\,$ is a root of their difference $X-Y$, which implies that $\,P\,$ divides $\,a_1 - b_1\,$ or, better, the first $\,a_i - b_i \neq 0.\,$ You can't say much more in general.